# Biconditional proof of odd factors and product

Tags: solution-verification

**EDIT 1:** Thanks @coffeemath for pointing out my mistake of defining both *m* and *n* in terms of *k*. They now each have their own respective constants for the Even and Odd forms.

**EDIT 2:** Fixed a typo

---

I'm trying to get my first proof down using quantifiers and math (or actual numbers) involved.

I have just a few questions:

- Is the claim section a correct representation of what's asking to be proved? (i.e. notation, binding order, etc)
- Is the structure of this proof clear?
- Is the proof itself sound?

Any other feedback is appreciated, but I'm really just aiming for the correct fundamentals before moving to anything advanced or applying optimizations.

Thanks,

### Prove

Let *m*,*n* denote any two natural numbers. Prove that *mn* is odd iff *m* and *n* are odd.

### Claim

$(\forall m\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})[(Odd(m) \wedge Odd(n)) \iff Odd(mn)]$

### Definitions

**Even**: A natural number with the form $2k$

**Odd**: A natural number with the form $2k + 1$

### Proof

$\Rightarrow$ $(Odd(m) \wedge Odd(n)) \iff Odd(mn)$

1. Assume both $m$ and $n$ are odd.
2. We can write $mn$ as $(2a+1)(2b+1)$
3. $(2a+1)(2b+1) = 4ab + 2a + 2b + 1$
4. $4ab + 2a + 2b + 1 = 2(2ab + a + b) + 1$
5. Note that $2(2ab + a + b) + 1$ has the Odd form.
6. $\therefore (Odd(m) \wedge Odd(n)) \implies Odd(mn)$

$\Leftarrow$ $Odd(mn) \implies (Odd(m) \wedge Odd(n))$

1. We will prove the contrapositive: $(Even(m) \lor Even(n)) \implies Even(mn)$
2. WLOG: Assume $m$ is even.
3. We can write $mn$ as $(2a)(n)$
4. $(2a)(n) = 2(an)$
5. Note that $2(an)$ has the Even form.
6. $\therefore (Even(m) \lor Even(n)) \implies Even(mn)$

Comment: At start you used the same letter $k$ for the odd numbers $m,n$ but that only works if $m=n,$ which is usually not true. You did the same thing a few other times.

Comment: Okay I see. I thought since k was, I guess undefined..., that possibly it could be reused like that. I will update to disambiguate. Edit: NVM I don't know why I thought that cause I even squared them. Thank you!